# Autosmooth causing subsurf problems with holes

Tags: modeling

As you can see when I use Autosmooth to get rid of the hole artefacts then my subsurf messes up. When its off my subsurf is fine but then the holes glitch out.

I am not sure what to do really :/

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the mesh's Data tab, create a new vertex group. Select only the vertices along the hole profiles and a couple of adjacent vertex loops. `CTRL+PLUS` ("grow selection") on the numpad is good for this. Click the button that says `Assign`.

Now go to the smoothing modifier and choose this vertex group. This prevents smoothing on any unintended vertices.